# Change only a specific element of an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, insert

I am trying to create a method that changes/updates specific elements of an array of objects by telling the user to insert 'null' for Strings and '0' for ints, meaning the default values and not changing the already existing values in my array. I tried this code, but my teacher said that I shouldn't use StandardInputRead for reading user's input. What should I do?

```
private void updateTask(String tID, String title, Date newFrom, Date newTo, status stat) 
{
        
        StandardInputRead sir = new StandardInputRead();
        int i;
        displayTasks();
        i = sir.readPositiveInt("Give task's index: \n");
        if(projectTasks[i]!=null) 
{
            System.out.println("Submit only the fields you want to change.");
            System.out.println("In any other case, type 'null' or '0' .");
            tID = sir.readString("Change the task's ID. \n");
            projectTasks[i].setTaskID(tID);
            title = sir.readString("Change the task's title. \n");
            projectTasks[i].setTaskTitle(title);
            newFrom = sir.readDate("Edit the starting date (DD/MM/YY). \n");
            projectTasks[i].setTaskFromDate(newFrom);
            newTo = sir.readDate("Edit the submission date (DD/MM/YY). \n");
            projectTasks[i].setTaskEndDate(newTo);
            //stat = Globals.status;
            projectTasks[i] = new Task(tID, title, newFrom, newTo, stat);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("There is no such task in our list.");
        
    }
```

Comment: You should ask your teacher what you should do instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this too and I think is better for my purpose:

```java
private void updateTask(String tID, String title, Date newFrom, Date newTo, status stat) {
        
    for(int i=0; i<this.numOfTasks; i++) {
        if(projectTasks[i]!=null) {
            if(tID!=null) {
                projectTasks[i].setTaskID(tID);
            } else if(tID ==null) {
                projectTasks[i].getTaskID();
            }
            if(title!=null) {
                projectTasks[i].setTaskTitle(title);
            } else if(title==null) {
                projectTasks[i].getTaskTitle();
            }
            if(newFrom!=null) {
                projectTasks[i].setTaskFromDate(newTo);
            } else if(newFrom==null) {
                projectTasks[i].getTaskFromDate();
            }
            if(newTo!=null) {
                projectTasks[i].setTaskEndDate(newTo);
            } else if(newTo==null) {
                projectTasks[i].getTaskEndDate();
            }
            if(stat!=null) {
                projectTasks[i].setTaskStatus(stat);
            } else if(stat==null) {
                projectTasks[i].getTaskStatus();
            }
            
            projectTasks[i] = new Task(tID, title, newFrom, newTo, stat);
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: As you always replace `projectTasks[i]` with a newly created object, your `if` statements have no effect.